# None in this world worked with Nhibernate and oracle stored procedure before?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, oracle10g

I am continuously posting the same kind of question but no one answering. This is the happening for the first time. Please help me if any one can.

Problem:

I have mapped my database table with NHibernate to C# class. But i need to call a stored procedure with some parameters. But NHibernate calls the stored procedure  with it's own wish! (i.e. NHibernate maintains an order of sequence for the stored procedure parameters). Now my question is, How do i know this order of sequence of parameters?

Iam using ASP.Net with C# in VS 2008 SP1, Oracle and NHibernate 1.2 version

Code:

```
<sql-insert>
  call strored_proc(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
</sql-insert>
```

Comment: I know this isn't helpful to the problem at hand, but a stored procedure with 40 parameters is probably best being re-factored to avoid such issues.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but i have no other options right now.

Comment: please post the code where you call the sproc.

Comment: If you aren't getting a response, then don't repost the question. Put a **bounty** on an old question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the order is static so that if you fire up NHProf and look at the sql it outputs you can order the parameters in the proc to match, although I do believe I've seen it where you can specify the order before.

Comment: how to use NHprof? Can you refer to tutorial or something?

Comment: Duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194757/nhibernate-oracle-stored-procedure-call-problem

Answer (score 0):

[15.3. Custom SQL for create, update and delete](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures)

> The order of the positional parameters
>   is currently vital, as they must be in
>   the same sequence as NHibernate
>   expects them.
>
> You can see the expected order by
>   enabling debug logging for the
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity level.
>   With this level enabled NHibernate
>   will print out the static SQL that is
>   used to create, update, delete etc.
>   entities. (To see the expected
>   sequence, remember to not include your
>   custom SQL in the mapping files as
>   that will override the NHibernate
>   generated static sql.)

I'd guess it's in the same order as the properties are mapped?

Answer (score 0):

You could so something like this.

```
session.CreateSQLQuery("call strored_proc(:a, :b, :c, :d)")
            .SetInt64("a", 54)
            .SetInt64("b", 544)
            .SetString("c", "your value")
            .SetInt64("d", 6546546)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Where a,b,c,d are parameters to your function.

Call .List() on it for it to return a 2 dimensional object array.

If want want to do a mapping:

```
<sql-query name="StoredProcName">
 call strored_proc(:a, :b, :c, :d)
</sql-query>
```

Then in your C# code

```
session.GetNamedQuery("StoredProcName")
            .SetInt64("a", 54)
            .SetInt64("b", 544)
            .SetString("c", "your value")
            .SetInt64("d", 6546546)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
```

or again call .List(); if you need results instead of .ExecuteUpdate();